# Why laravel_session cookie exists in browser when session lifetime was already expired?

Tags: laravel, cookies

I use Sanctum to authenticate my SPA. For experiment I set lifetime property to 1 minute in session.php config file. After 1 minute requests from my SPA to laravel backend became unauthenticated which is okay and expected behaviour. But when I check for cookies in cookies section of Application tab of google chrome development panel, laravel_session cookie and XSRF-TOKEN cookie still exist there which is strange and undesired behavior. Why is it so and how to make them disappear after session expiration?

Comment: Cookies stored on the client side do not magically disappear, just because you did some cleaning-up on the server side. You would need to respond to the next request by any particular client with the appropriate Set-Cookie headers to delete those cookies.

Comment: Thanks, I will know it. There is another weird thing, with each request to backend the value of  laravel_session cookie updates and the expiration date of cookie updates as well. Is it supposed to be that way?

Comment: Yes it is. Everytime you make a request you trigger the storage of a CSRF cookie. Just take a look at sanctums CsrfCookieController (the one that response to 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'). It's just one method that returns an empty JsonResponse to trigger the storage of the CSRF cookie in the browser.